# Calling DelegatingHandler with injected service

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor webassembly app with a class that is called to send HTTPClient requests.

This class needs access to data stored in Local Storage. This local storage is contained in an interface/cla[image]ss that I have added to the constructor of the DelegatingHandler class.

I can't work out how to add this IBrowserStorageService service when creating the HTTPClient service.

Can anyone please assist with the correct syntax. I've tried numerous different approaches, but to no avail.

I've looked at similar topics, but they are subtly different and don't help.

[image]

**UPDATE**
Someone posted that I change the program.cs to use this builder.

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("NewClient", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
.AddHttpMessageHandler();

I worked out that I had to modify the service where the HTTP calls are made from. Previously the constructor for this service looked like this

```
    public AuthService(HttpClient httpClient, IBrowserStorageService localStorService)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _localStorService = localStorService;
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Settings.API_BaseUrl);
    }
```

...

but I realised I would have to change the constructor to create the client, so I did this

```
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly IBrowserStorageService _localStorService;

    public AuthService(IBrowserStorageService localStorService, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {

        _httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient");
        _localStorService = localStorService;

    }
```

This generates a heap of errors when the _httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient"); executes, which starts of with this
"Unhandled exception rendering component: The 'InnerHandler' property must be null. 'DelegatingHandler' instances provided to 'HttpMessageHandlerBuilder' must not be reused or cached."

Answer (score 0):

You need to first scope your delegating handler, then your http client, in your middleware like so:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<AddHeadersDelegatingHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyClient")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<AddHeadersDelegatingHandler>();
```

Comment: Please see update in original post